# Java jsp taglib

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

I frequently saw links to "external tag libraries" in jsp
Ex:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
```

But I couldn't find answers to these questions:

- Does use a tag library from an external web location?

  - Does it query that location every time the tag is used?
  - Does it download it only once?

    - when does the download happen?
- Can I create my own tag library, and provide a similar external link to others?

Please edit this question if it's wrong, I never really asked questions of this type

Comment: I think these paragraphs explain most of what is unclear to you: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro9.html#wp73319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer bold replies

- Does use a tag library from an external web location? **No**

  - Does it query that location every time the tag is used?  **No**
  - Does it download it only once? **No download so no query**

    - when does the download happen? **Download never happens**
- Can I create my own tag library, and provide a similar external link to others? **Yes**

The uri you see the JSP page, is actually referenced from web.xml file, refer to [jsp-config](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/web_xml.html#wp1071166).

Answer (score 3):

A tag library is part of the application, no download is happening at runtime. The URL you see on the JSP page is just a namespace URI to bind the prefix used on the page to the tag library.

Yes, you can create your own tag library.